# How to identify the status of a toggle button?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have some thing like there is a toggle button of having "Show" and "Hide" as values, I want to know the status of the button before i am going to perform some action on this toggle button.
The code looks like:

```
<td class="OC_hide_show">
<div class="toggle">
<select id="id1" class="some class name" data-role="isnsd"   name="selectcommand">
<div class="some class names" role="application">
<span class="Some class names" role="img" style="width: 0%;">Show</span>
<span class="some class names" role="img" style="width: 100%;">Hide</span>          
<div class="ui">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical guess would be checking the element property:

`bool isDisplayed = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Show']").isDisplayed;`

Should this not work (because you're using the CSS width instead of CSS display), try:

```
String s = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Show']").getAttribute("style");
if(s.Contains("100%"))
{
  // the show button is visible
}
else
{
  // the hide button is presumably visible
}
```

Comment: That helped me in solving the problem.However as per my knowledge we are not suppose to use "style" attribute to find the element status. Please correct if am wrong.

Comment: @DasojuShiva Yes, using attributes to determine a status is just a workaround if the element properties are not sufficient. If your problem is resolved, please mark my reply as answer (check the V mark) so the question doesn't remain open.